# Reclaim progression after deleting app

Tags: ios

Occasionaly I try to clean up my iOS-device by deleting apps that I barely use, which includes games. I've played a lot of games on my iOS-device, some will release new content after a few months, some won't.

What will happen to my progression if I delete an app and the developer decides to release new content that I'd like to play. Will I have to restart from scratch, is my progression saved or is this up to the developer? Are there any ways to back-up progression before deleting an app?

Comment: Is there a specific game you are thinking of? In my experience, it depends on how much is tied to your device vs an account.

Comment: No, it's a question about iOS-games in general. I know there are games that built their own online infrastructure for save data, but I'd like to know how I can keep my progression on a game that doesn't have this option.

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't have cloud saves, you'll have to start from scratch. There aren't really any ways to back up your data. It could be possible that restoring your device to six months ago when you had it installed *might* have the relevant save data, but I can't promise that, and it would be awfully inconvenient anyways.